# Rails 3 app - Best possible way to Connect with Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, model-view-controller, oauth

We are new to rails and are looking to use the Javascript SDK "Connect with Facebook" button on our homepage. Using this button in our app, we want to allow users to sign up for our site via Facebook, and be able to use their Facebook profile picture as their profile image for our web app.

What is the best way to implement this Facebook Connection with our Rails 3 app?

```
  devise_for :users

  resources :authentications

  resources :users do
      member do
        get :following, :followers
      end
  end
  resources :sessions,   :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, :only => [:create, :destroy]

  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/home',   :to => 'pages#home'
  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
  match '/feedback',    :to => 'pages#feedback'
  match '/privacy',    :to => 'pages#privacy'
  match '/terms',    :to => 'pages#terms'
  match '/',        :to => 'pages#home'

  resources :microposts

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]


  root :to => 'pages#home'

  match "/auth/twitter/callback" => "sessions#omnicreate"
  match "/auth/facebook/callback" => "sessions#omnicreate"


end
```

SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @title = "Sign in"
  end

  def create
      user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                           params[:session][:password])
      if user.nil?
        flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
        @title = "Sign in"
        render 'new'
      else
        sign_in user
        redirect_back_or user
      end
  end

  def destroy
        sign_out
        redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to do a couple things:

Change these lines in your routes file:

```
  root :to => 'pages#home'

  match "/auth/twitter/callback" => "sessions#omnicreate"
  match "/auth/facebook/callback" => "sessions#omnicreate"
```

To this:

```
  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#omnicreate"

  root :to => 'pages#home' # this one should always be last
```

Both Twitter and Facbook are going to the same method so you will need to get that `:provider` param out later on to figure out if its Twitter or Facebook that sent them.

Next you need to create a method in your `SessionsController` that receives the callback like this:

```
def omnicreate

  data = request.env['omniauth.auth'] # here is all the user data
  if params[:provider] == 'twitter'
     #parse twitter data
  elsif params[:provider] == 'facebook'
     #parse fb data
  else
     # something is broken
     redirect_to '/404.html'
  end

  user = User.create! #use data you parsed to create a user
  redirect_to some_path, :notice => 'awwww yeah'
end
```

good luck!

Comment: thanks Matthew we ran that and came across this error. We're getting this
`RecordInvalid in SessionsController#omnicreate`
`Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Password can't be blank`

Comment: i'm going to add our `SessionsController` take a quick look and let us know what you think

Comment: All the parts of my answer with comments are places where you need to fill in the blanks. You need to parse the `data` param and use the result to pass the params to `User.create!`

Comment: can we get a few hints as to how to parse this data? it's our first app, we're rookies to heavy duty rails applications and authentications.

Comment: were currently differentiating sessions by email

Comment: watch the video tutorial I sent you here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

Answer (score 2):

The [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) gem is a great way to set up authentication via a third party service. They have a facebook strategy. I have used it and it was dead simple to set up. Just stick you api keys in a rails initializer.

Comment: Yeah, we've used OmniAuth and cant seem to get it to work. Do we need to make modifications in the User model or in our controllers?

Comment: Yes you do have to make some changes. Basically the way it works is you redirect your users to Facebook then facecbook redirects them back to your site and passes you some data (eg a auth token and a url for their profile pic). Omniauth parses this data for you and makes it manageble, but you need to set up a route for the users to get redirected to after authentication on Facebook.com.

tl;dr watch this screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

Comment: Yeah, it is our routes callback that is completely out of order. We are good up until the point where Facebook redirects the User back to our app. We get the error `Unknown action` `The action 'omnicreate' could not be found for SessionsController`

Comment: can you put up your routes file? (or the relavent parts) you should have something like this:

`match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'`

Comment: sure man here goes, we are also having trouble understanding how devise works in our app with relation to devise, just a web of issues here, lol.